# How to handle Python exceptions depending on the calling function?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

```
def lower_level_function():
    try:
        x = 1 / 0
    except Exception:
        # If this function was called directly, handle the exception
        # - OR - 
        # If this function was called by another function in my code, 
        # allow the exception to be handled at the upper level
```

I'd like to handle exceptions at the upper-most level. However, I have a function (like the horrible example above) that can either be called as part of the run of another function in my code, or called "directly" as part of an API call by the user. How can I ensure that any exceptions thrown are either reraised or handled at this level, depending on how this function was called?

Comment: Don't call it directly. Use another function for the API.

Comment: +++ to Barmar's comment.  One function should do one thing.  If you need two entirely different sets of behaviors, have two functions, even if one just wraps the other in a `try/except`.

Comment: What does *directly* mean? Any call of the function will either be from another function of at the module level. If you want different behaviour on the module level, use the `if __name__ == <module_name>` guard.

Comment: My advice is to either completely handle the exception inside a function and the calling function does not need to know anything about it, or, throw (raise) it to the calling level. Eventually create your own exception class, if the standard exceptions do not fit.